# Paperclip not running tasks but not showing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is strange. I just did a deploy to a cluster server, and since then, pictures have not been processing. Reading the logs, I usually do not get an error at all, but they never finish. However, on one particular image, I found this little bit at least, but this might not explain everything.. Any ideas?

Processing PhotosController#edit (for 69.248.152.173 at 2010-05-27 04:25:12) [GET]
  Parameters: {"gallery_id"=>"2102", "action"=>"edit", "type"=>"photo", "id"=>"15453", "crop"=>"true", "controller"=>"photos", "organization_id"=>"470", "_"=>"1274959512393"}
Rendering media/crop_photo

ActionView::TemplateError (/data/HQ_Channel/releases/20100524111501/public/system/photos/15453/original/DSC05193.JPG is not recognized by the 'identify' command.) on line #4 of app/views/media/crop_photo.js.haml:
1: == $("#media_header").html('#{ escape_javascript(render :partial => 'media/crop_photo') }').slideDown("slow");
2: 
3: :plain
4:   function updateForm(coords)
5:   {
6:    var rx =  #{PHOTO_IMAGE_WIDTH} / coords.w;
7:    var ry = #{PHOTO_IMAGE_HEIGHT} / coords.h;

```
vendor/gems/thoughtbot-paperclip-2.3.1/lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:24:in `from_file'
app/models/photo.rb:68:in `photo_geometry'
app/views/media/crop_photo.js.haml:4:in `_run_haml_app47views47media47crop_photo46js46haml'
haml (2.2.2) [v] lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:81:in `crop'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:24:in `edit'
haml (2.2.2) [v] rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
lib/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.2.2/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
```

** [Hoptoad] Failure: Net::HTTPClientError
** [Hoptoad] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.8.6] [Rails: 2.3.3] [Env: production]
** [Hoptoad] Response from Hoptoad: 


  No project exists with the given API key.

Rendering /data/HQ_Channel/releases/20100524111501/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)

And then a little later, I got this :

ActionView::TemplateError (/data/HQ_Channel/releases/20100524111501/public/system/photos/15453/original/DSC05193.JPG is not recognized by the 'identify' command.) on line #4 of app/views/media/crop_photo.js.haml:
1: == $("#media_header").html('#{ escape_javascript(render :partial => 'media/crop_photo') }').slideDown("slow");
2: 
3: :plain
4:   function updateForm(coords)
5:   {
6:    var rx =  #{PHOTO_IMAGE_WIDTH} / coords.w;
7:    var ry = #{PHOTO_IMAGE_HEIGHT} / coords.h;

```
vendor/gems/thoughtbot-paperclip-2.3.1/lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:24:in `from_file'
app/models/photo.rb:68:in `photo_geometry'
app/views/media/crop_photo.js.haml:4:in `_run_haml_app47views47media47crop_photo46js46haml'
haml (2.2.2) [v] lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:81:in `crop'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:24:in `edit'
haml (2.2.2) [v] rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
lib/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.2.2/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
```

** [Hoptoad] Failure: Net::HTTPClientError
** [Hoptoad] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.8.6] [Rails: 2.3.3] [Env: production]
** [Hoptoad] Response from Hoptoad: 


  No project exists with the given API key.

Rendering /data/HQ_Channel/releases/20100524111501/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a simmilar issue. It looks paperclip cant find path to execute image processing commands 
Add this to product environment file:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/path/to/image/processor(ImageMagick)/bin"
```

in my case it was

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

or set a global path to ImageMagick in the host system

Comment: Would that go in your production.rb or environment in config/environments?

Comment: Tried this, and it didn't work. I wonder if there is a way to access a log explicit to just imagemagick. Because in my production.log, I can't find any errors.

Comment: did you find a correct path in your production server using which?
in my case:
$ which identify
/usr/local/bin/identify
In case you get empty response, you have no ImageMagick installed in your prod server or the path is not set.
Add the line to production.rb, because config/environments will also make effect on testing, dev and staging environments.
I still believe that is the cause of problem, because I had the same error reports and people are talking this solved their problem http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=s+not+recognized+by+the+'identify'+command.

Comment: Mine is in usr/bin . I set it to such in my config/environments/production.rb . But it didn't help. I wonder if there is a way to inspect if its delayed jobs not sending it to imagemagick. Thanks for all your help.